# Can't figure out why this numbers to words function doesn't work

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write a function that takes any number from 1-999 and turns it into words ( 345 --> "three hundred forty five", etc). I'm pretty new to Javascript, so the code is a little messy, but it works for everything greater than 19. Anything less than or equal to 19 returns a blank, and I can't for the life of me figure out why, and it's giving me a headache.

```js
function wordify(n){
 var number = n;
 function teensToWord(num){
  switch (num){
   case 10: return "ten";
   case 11: return "eleven";
   case 12: return "twelve";
   case 13: return "thirteen";
   case 14: return "fourteen";
   case 15: return "fifteen";
   case 16: return "sixteen";
   case 17: return "seventeen";
   case 18: return "eighteen";
   case 19: return "nineteen";
  }    
 }
 function toWord(digit){
  switch (digit){
   case 1: return "one";
   case 2: return "two";
   case 3: return "three";
   case 4: return "four";
   case 5: return "five";
   case 6: return "six";
   case 7: return "seven";
   case 8: return "eight";
   case 9: return "nine";
   case 0: return "";
  }

 }
 function tensToWord(digit) {
  switch (digit){
   case 2: return "twenty";
   case 3: return "thirty";
   case 4: return "forty";
   case 5: return "fifty";
   case 6: return "sixty";
   case 7: return "seventy";
   case 8: return "eighty";
   case 9: return "ninety";
   case 0: return "";
  }
 }
 function reduceOnes (num) {
  var onesPlace = num;
  if(onesPlace < 10){return onesPlace;}
  else{onesPlace -= 10;}
  return reduceOnes(onesPlace);
 }
 function reduceTens (num) {
  var tensPlace = num;
  if(tensPlace < 100){return tensPlace;}
  else{tensPlace -=100;}
  return reduceTens(tensPlace);
 }

 var numArr = [];

 var ones = reduceOnes(n);

 n = n-ones;

 var tens = reduceTens(n)/10;

 n = n - (tens*10);

 var hundreds = n/100;
 
 if(number>=10 && number<=19){
  numArr.unshift(teensToWord(number));
 }else if(number<10){
  numArr.unshift(toWord(number));
 }else{
  numArr.unshift(toWord(ones));
  if(number>=10){
   numArr.unshift(tensToWord(tens));
   if(number>=100){
    numArr.unshift(toWord(hundreds)+ " hundred");
   }
  }
 }
 
 return numArr.join(' ');
}
```

Comment: Can't reproduce, your code is working here, for everything from 1 to 999. Only zero gives an empty string.

Comment: Code seems to be working: [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/puyegorowo/1/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: You're right, it does work in the browser. That's really odd. I've been testing it with nodeJS in the terminal, and that's where it's not working. That doesn't seem like it should make a difference though....

Comment: Tested in node in a terminal, still works.